# Changing the root folder via .htaccess and ignore path

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, root

I want the public/ folder to be root but I want to ignore everything that comes in the url, but the files in the css, javascript, images folder are accessible.

Example:

`http://localhost/` access to `public/` folder

`http://localhost/css/style.css` or `http://localhost/js/script.js` or `http://localhost/images/funny.gif` is accessible

I want it when I type `http://localhost/news/1?test=helloword`

`news/1?test=helloword` need be ignored, but in PHP when using the parse_url() function I have to have access to all variables, like ['path'],['query;],...

Output:

```
['path'] => '/news/1'

['query'] => {
    ['test'] => 'helloword'
}
```

I'm using PHP to make the server `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/` it works very well

but when i enter the `apache2` server it doesn't work

I found this on the internet `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

just don't ignore the `[path],[query],...`

Hope I'm not being an idiot asking this :/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this out? I have given an example to redirect to index page so you may modify a bit for the index.php .

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule (.*) /? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This externally redirects everything to the document root. The OP is wanting to do the complete opposite, ie. internally rewrite all requests (except for static resources) to the `/public` subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using PHP to make the server `php -S ...`

The webserver built into PHP is not Apache and so does not use `.htaccess`. You *need* to use Apache (`.htaccess`) in order to rewrite requests to the `/public` subdirectory.

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
>
> RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
> ```

These directives are on the right track, except they would also rewrite your CSS, JS and images. So you need some additional *condition(s)* to exclude these 3 subdirectories.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule !^(public|css|js|images)($|/) public/index.php [L,NC]
```

This assumes that the only static resources that need to be accessed outside of the `public` subdirectory are contained in the 3 subdirectories mentioned. This avoids the need for a filesystem check.

You then parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in `/public/index.php` to extract the requested URL information.

**UPDATE:** I removed the `RewriteCond` directive before the last rule since the check can be performed in the `RewriteRule` directive itself.

NB: The redirect (first rule) is for SEO only and not integral to the process (as you should be linking to the URL without `/public`). Ultimately, this redirect should be a 301 (permanent) redirect once you have confirmed it works as intended.

Comment: I wasn't using .htaccess on PHP's http server, after switching to apache2 I had this problem, but I've found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, but I've found a solution. :)

Project folder:

```
config/
public/
    - css/
    - js/
    - index.php
src/
```

I used this in the project root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

And in the `public/` folder use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}%  !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}%  !-f

RewriteRule \.(js|css|svg|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$                index.php?router=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and it works very well, for those who have this problem, here's the solution

This my code parse url: https://ibb.co/r6HR1Qd

Comment: Although this would still (unconditionally) rewrite requests for `/css/style.css` to `/public/css/style.css` etc. ? This also works differently to how you stated in the question... using a `router` URL parameter. It results in different output as stated. (?) It also rewrites requests back to `/index.php` in the document root, not `/public/index.php` as stated in your file structure?

Comment: like css, js folders, they are in the `public/` folder and the router is there for being there, it works only that the variable `$_GET` does not show the querys. when I need `/news/1?lang=eng` in `$_GET ['router']` it doesn't show `?lang=eng` , but in parse_url I have a list of all parameters like `['path'] => array([0] => 'news'), ['query'] => array(['lang'] => 'eng')` `!! in my code !!`

Comment: "like css, js folders, they are in the `public/` folder" - Ah, OK, although that wasn't clear in your question - it seemed that your static resources were located in the document root. However, your `public/.htaccess` file cannot work as written - all your static resources would be routed to `/index.php` (in the document root). (?!)